# How can i view the entire matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I exported a matrix of 127x127 values as a txt, but the output appears as

```
 answer:[[  44.    1.    0. ...,   12.   13.    2.]
 [  51.    7.    0. ...,    5.   14.    4.]
 [   0.    1.    4. ...,    0.    0.    1.]
 ..., 
 [  22.  110.   70. ...,    5.    0.    0.]
 [  12.   36.   12. ...,    0.    0.    2.]
 [   0.    0.    0. ...,   24.  177.   53.]]
```

I need access to all values, as input on Support Vector Machines

Thank You

Comment: exported from what? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using numpy. If that's the case, I suggest you use the savetxt() function (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to change the number of items returned when the array is printed.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(127*127).reshape(127, 127)
>>> np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=127)
>>> print a
```

As expected this will flood your screen.